# System.InvalidCastException with string isolatedstorage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, exception, isolatedstorage

I get this exception on the following code.
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Project.DLL but was not handled in user code.

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("0"))
{
    string temp = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["0"];//exception here
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but to debug could you put this line in to find out the type: Console.WriteLine(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["0"].GetType());

Comment: What do you store a value in AppSettings? How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem!
Here is what I did:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("0"))
{
   string temp = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["0"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What do you store a value in AppSettings? How do you do it?

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

An `InvalidCastException` exception is thrown when the conversion of an instance of one type to another type is not supported. It differs from an OverflowException exception, which is thrown when a conversion of one type to another is supported, but the value of the source type is outside the range of the target type.

What type of data are you storing at key `"0"`? You should be typecasting the Value of key `0` to string before saving it, corresponding to the Dictionary data type?

Comment: I store a Name (so string type).
how do i typecast the value of the key?